# How to change the middle node location in the torrc?

Tags: tor

I am trying to edit my torrc and make all of the nodes funnel through one country.

So far I am able to force the entry and exit nodes but don't know how to change the middle node... any ideas?
I have already tried "MiddleNodes" and "RelayNodes"

```
EntryNodes {us},{ca}
ExitNodes {us},{ca} 
StrictNodes 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to restrict to MiddleNodes per Tor docs: https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

> MiddleNodes node,node,…
>   A list of identity fingerprints and country
>   codes of nodes to use for "middle" hops in your normal circuits.
>   Normal circuits include all circuits except for direct connections to
>   directory servers. Middle hops are all hops other than exit and entry.
>   This is an **experimental** feature that is meant to be used by
>   researchers and developers to test new features in the Tor network
>   safely. Using it without care will strongly influence your anonymity.
>   This feature might get removed in the future. The HSLayer2Node and
>   HSLayer3Node options override this option for onion service circuits,
>   if they are set. The vanguards addon will read this option, and if
>   set, it will set HSLayer2Nodes and HSLayer3Nodes to nodes from this
>   set. The ExcludeNodes option overrides this option: any node listed in
>   both MiddleNodes and ExcludeNodes is treated as excluded. See the
>   **ExcludeNodes** option for more information on how to specify nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See new answer by @user1652110 describing `MiddleNodes` option which was added in January 2019.

<strike>There is no option to do so.  The closest option you can try is [`ExcludeNodes`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExcludeNodes) by using as large a list of country codes as you can come up with that doesn't include the countries you do want to use.</strike>

Also note, at the time of writing, limiting your circuits' entry and exit points to relays in the US and Canada might severely limit your performance, anonymity, and reliability since there just aren't that many high-bandwidth exits and guards in these two countries.